# Is there a glossary about which infrared (IR) colors which body parts reflect?

Tags: bacteriology, organs, surgery, color

I am doing medical research and I'm trying to find parts of the body that look about the same to the human eye, but reflect different "colors" in IR, so that using a light source and a camera of that frequency helps to distinguish between them. Thus I was wondering if there is a glossary out there that lists all the colors (visible or invisible to the human eye) for all body parts (cells, bacteria, organs etc.) that get reflected.

I'd also be interested in literature on that topic, but it's sort of difficult to feed the right words into search engines without getting tons of unrelated results.

Comment: Are you referring to dead bodies? Because living human tissue emits a lot of IR radiation but in comparison hardly reflects any. There are actually not many natural materials that reflect IR well.

Comment: I refer mainly to living human bodies, but some test runs will include dead animal meat as well, and whether IR light is emitted or reflected is actually not that important to me, so I'm basically interested in both. But thanks for the info that not many natural materials reflect IR well.

Comment: Whether you want to detect reflected or emitted light should be incredibly important to you. Those are very different approaches that require different equipment. I think you should talk to someone from the department of physics.